Custom kernel doesn't boot on proxmox
I have built a 6.10 kernel using gcc (with .config from generic ubuntu) on Ubuntu 24.04.
I am able to run it on Ubuntu but not on Proxmox.
On Proxmox, I get following error:
Alert! /dev/mapper/pve-root does not exist. Dropping to shell

Running lvm pvscan returns nothin, and adding rootdelay=10 to grub also didn't help.
I was trying to re-generate the initrd image for this kernel on Proxmox but the same problem still exists.
It looks like my new kernel is not able to see my lvm partition on Proxmox.
My setup: Xeon x3440, 24GB RAM, Intel S3420GP main board, ssd 512GB
Any ideas what to do?

Have you tried building the kernel on Proxmox?

yes.  The same problem.

Most likely your new kernel does not have the driver for the (virtual) disk controller provided by Proxmox.
Proxmox VE documentation says:

Proxmox VE emulates by default a LSI 53C895A controller.

and

It is highly recommended to use the VirtIO SCSI or VirtIO Block controller for performance reasons and because they are better maintained.

So the relevant kernel configuration options would be CONFIG_SCSI_VIRTIO for VirtIO SCSI, CONFIG_VIRTIO_BLK for VirtIO Block, and CONFIG_SCSI_SYM53C8XX_2 for the emulated SCSI controller.

I have rebuild kernel with missing CONFIG_SCSI_SYM53C8XX_2 config and the problem still appears. First two configs already been in old kernel.
